# Difference between non-stationary and random process.

Tags: statistics

What is difference between non-stationary and random data. To my understanding, non-stationary data is the one whose mean, variance and co-variance change over time. The same must be true for random data which does not have any fixed mean or variance.

Answer (score 0):

A non-stationary process has a distribution law that varies over time. The fact mean, variance and autocorrelation change over time is a sufficient but not necessary condition.

A random process is just a process whose values cannot be known at the beginning of the process. You can have non-stationary process as well as stationary process.